# Converting a list into a dictionary python3

Tags: python

I have a list 
`['E:3', 'B:13', 'G:6', 'F:|=', 'H:}{', 'I:!', 'B:|3', 'K:|{', '']`
and I would like to convert it into a dictionary `{'E':'3', 'B':'13', 'G':'6', 'F':'|=', 'H':'}{', 'I':'!', 'B':'|3', 'K':'|{'}`

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: A dictionary can not contain duplicated keys, so you won't be able to have two items having `B` as keys as in your result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply split it on `:` and send it to `dict()`, filtering out the empty string:

```
>>> l = ['E:3', 'B:13', 'G:6', 'F:|=', 'H:}{', 'I:!', 'B:|3', 'K:|{', '']
>>> result = dict(item.split(':') for item in l if item)
>>> result
{'I': '!', 'H': '}{', 'K': '|{', 'E': '3', 'G': '6', 'B': '|3', 'F': '|='}
```

Also note that, as Psidom says [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954423/converting-a-list-into-a-dictionary-python3/40954453#comment69118553_40954423), dictionaries cannot contain duplicate keys, so only the most recent duplicate will end up in the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this through a dict comprehension.  This will loop through the list, splitting each item into two parts using the first for the dict key and the second for the value.

```
example_dict = {x.split(":")[0]: x.split(":")[1] for x in example_list if x}
```

Comment: This will crash due to the empty string.

Comment: Just add an `if x` at the end of your comprehension

Comment: Also note that you're splitting `x` twice unnecessarily.